# How to finish a payment transation - in app purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, in-app-purchase

I am implementing in app purchase (non consumable type - songs ).when a user taps buy for every song purchase i call **startPurchase funtion**.my song content is delivered via my server.

In that when i purchased something and again try to re purchase the same, it is not treated as restore of purchase.it makes a new purchase.the delegate methods are called multiple times

Actually what is my problem is, i tap buy and proceed with the payment, and purchased that item.

Again when i try to buy the same item the apple alert says as "**You have already purchased this item, tap ok to download" when i tap "OK**".this is not coming under **SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored** instead it goes to **SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased**.why this is happening? pls help

Please help me out

```
- (void)startPurchase:(NSString*)inProductId{

  if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
  {
     myProductId = inProductId

    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:myProductId]];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];
  }
  else {
    NSLog(@"Parental-controls are enabled");
      }

}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:
  (SKProductsResponse *)response {

  NSLog(@"response received");
  SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
  int count = [response.products count];

  UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:
  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",response.products.count] delegate:
  self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

  [alert show];
  [alert release];

  if (count > 0) {
    validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"products available");
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:myProductId];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
  }
  else if (!validProduct) {
    NSLog(@"No products available");
  }
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        SKPayment *payment = [transaction payment];

      if([payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:myProductId])
      {
          NSLog(@"%@payement queue payment.productIdentifier",payment.productIdentifier);

        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                NSLog(@"completeTransaction");
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"failedTransaction");
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"restoreTransaction");
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
      }
    }
}

- (void)provideContent:(NSString *)productIdentifier
{
    NSLog(@"Provide Content %@", productIdentifier);

    }

- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSLog(@"inside the recordTransaction");

}

- (void) completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    [self recordTransaction: transaction];
    [self provideContent: transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];


}

- (void) restoreTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    NSLog(@"restoreTransaction transaction inside");

   }

- (void) failedTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"Unknown Error (%d), product: %@", (int)transaction.error.code, transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
            UIAlertView *failureAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle :@"In-App-Purchase Error:"
            message: @"There was an error purchasing this item please try again."
            delegate : self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [failureAlert show];
            [failureAlert release];
        }

        if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorClientInvalid) {
            NSLog(@"Client invalid (%d), product: %@", (int)transaction.error.code, transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
            UIAlertView *failureAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle :@"In-App-Purchase Error:"
            message: @"There was an error purchasing this item please try again."
            delegate : self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [failureAlert show];
            [failureAlert release];
        }

        if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentInvalid) {
            NSLog(@"Payment invalid (%d), product: %@", (int)transaction.error.code, transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
            UIAlertView *failureAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle :@"In-App-Purchase Error:"
            message: @"There was an error purchasing this item please try again."
            delegate : self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [failureAlert show];
            [failureAlert release];
        }

        if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed) {
            NSLog(@"Payment not allowed (%d), product: %@", (int)transaction.error.code, transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
            UIAlertView *failureAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle :@"In-App-Purchase Error:"
            message: @"There was an error purchasing this item please try again."
            delegate : self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [failureAlert show];
            [failureAlert release];
        }
    }
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```

Comment: discuss chat with me http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13214/discussion-between-dinesh-and-user198725878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem add transaction server duplicate reflecting
Try below code for avoid add transaction server duplicate may be it's worked:

```
- (void)startPurchase:(NSString*)inProductId{

  if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
  {
     myProductId = inProductId

    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:myProductId]];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];
  }
  else {
    NSLog(@"Parental-controls are enabled");
      }

}
static bool hasAddObserver=NO;
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:
  (SKProductsResponse *)response {

  NSLog(@"response received");
  SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
  int count = [response.products count];

  UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:
  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",response.products.count] delegate:
  self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

  [alert show];
  [alert release];

  if (count > 0) {
    validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"products available");
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:myProductId];
    if (!hasAddObserver) {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    hasAddObserver=YES;
    }
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
  }
  else if (!validProduct) {
    NSLog(@"No products available");
  }
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        SKPayment *payment = [transaction payment];

      if([payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:myProductId])
      {
          NSLog(@"%@payement queue payment.productIdentifier",payment.productIdentifier);

        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                NSLog(@"completeTransaction");
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"failedTransaction");
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"restoreTransaction");
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
      }
    }
}

- (void)provideContent:(NSString *)productIdentifier
{
    NSLog(@"Provide Content %@", productIdentifier);

    }

- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSLog(@"inside the recordTransaction");

}

- (void) completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    [self recordTransaction: transaction];
    [self provideContent: transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];


}

- (void) restoreTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    NSLog(@"restoreTransaction transaction inside");

   }

- (void) failedTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"Unknown Error (%d), product: %@", (int)transaction.error.code, transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
            UIAlertView *failureAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle :@"In-App-Purchase Error:"
            message: @"There was an error purchasing this item please try again."
            delegate : self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [failureAlert show];
            [failureAlert release];
        }

        if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorClientInvalid) {
            NSLog(@"Client invalid (%d), product: %@", (int)transaction.error.code, transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
            UIAlertView *failureAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle :@"In-App-Purchase Error:"
            message: @"There was an error purchasing this item please try again."
            delegate : self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [failureAlert show];
            [failureAlert release];
        }

        if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentInvalid) {
            NSLog(@"Payment invalid (%d), product: %@", (int)transaction.error.code, transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
            UIAlertView *failureAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle :@"In-App-Purchase Error:"
            message: @"There was an error purchasing this item please try again."
            delegate : self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [failureAlert show];
            [failureAlert release];
        }

        if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed) {
            NSLog(@"Payment not allowed (%d), product: %@", (int)transaction.error.code, transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
            UIAlertView *failureAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle :@"In-App-Purchase Error:"
            message: @"There was an error purchasing this item please try again."
            delegate : self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [failureAlert show];
            [failureAlert release];
        }
    }
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```

In your i am check the transaction server is added or not below code:

```
if (!hasAddObserver) {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    hasAddObserver=YES;
    }
```

hasAddObserver Variable static bool datatype is check if already added easy to added check transaction server!

Comment: Hi, i tried your code. but it is still showing as purchased not coming to restore of purchase

Comment: did u want to restore transactions

Comment: you can try [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]; before purchase calling!

Comment: Actually what is my problem is, i tap buy and proceed with the payment, and purchased that item.again when i try to buy the same item the apple alert says as " you have already purchased this item, tap ok to download" when i tap "OK".this is not coming under SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored instead it goes to SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased.why this is happening? pls help

Comment: i am identify your problem you must check before purchase product is already purchased or not ok you call first [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]; and after - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions method called to check if([transactions count]==0){//if zero not already purchased  SKMutablePayment *payment = [[[SKMutablePayment alloc] init] autorelease];
    payment.productIdentifier = @"com.mycompany.apppro";
    payment.quantity = 1;
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];}  come discuss

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13214/discussion-between-dinesh-and-user198725878)

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour as far as [official Apple documentation][1] says:
"If the user attempts to purchase a restorable product (instead of using the restore interface you implemented), **the application receives a regular transaction for that item, not a restore transaction**. However, the user is not charged again for that product. Your application should treat these transactions identically to those of the original transaction."